# Get Firebase email signin token for backend testing

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on a backend project that has several endpoint APIs. Some of our APIs must verify an email signed-in token by iOS/Android app users. Is there a practical way to retrieve Firebase Auth Email signed-in token for my test? It is not cool to ask for a token from app developers each time I do a test on backend :)  I know there is a curl command to get an anonymous token. And know that, email sign-in has one more async step to confirm the link. Is there any way to reproduce it thru curl/SoapUI (without setting up a web-app)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are referring to the Firebase ID Tokens which you verify on the server. Essentially you just need to call the Google Identity Toolkit API with your test account credentials that Firebase SDK does behind the scenes.

You need to make a `POST` request at the following URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=<FIREBASE_API_KEY>
```

`FIREBASE_API_KEY` can you be found in your web app's configuration that is required to initialize the client SDK.

You must add a JSON body containing the email and password of the user you are trying to log in along with a property `returnSecureToken` set to true.

Here's the curl request for the same:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=FIREBASE_API_KEY' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
    "email": "username@domain.tld",
    "password": "password",
    "returnSecureToken": true
}'
```

This will return an object similar to this:

```
{
  "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyPasswordResponse",
  "localId": "",
  "email": "username@domain.tld",
  "displayName": "",
  "idToken": "firebase_id_token",
  "registered": true,
  "refreshToken": "refresh_token",
  "expiresIn": "3600"
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dharmaraj. I just tested it quick, and get below response. Yes, I am 100% sure my email/password and API key are correct
{
 

 "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INVALID_PASSWORD",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "INVALID_PASSWORD",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: @Psyduck I'd try creating a new account from the console and try again.